# Next: Backs to pre previous route when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When i click this button i get back to prev route which is fine.
Example: /profile/media -> /profile/settings -> /profile/media.

```
 <button onClick={() => router.back()} className="save-btn">
            Save
 </button>
```

But when i click outside of modal i get back to pre previous route can't get it.
Example: /following -> /profile/media -> /profile/settings -> /following.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const closeOnClickOutside = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      if (
        editModal.current &&
        e.target !== null &&
        !editModal.current.contains(e.target as Node)
      ) {
        router.back();
      }
    };

    return editModal
      ? document.addEventListener("mouseup", closeOnClickOutside)
      : document.removeEventListener("mouseup", closeOnClickOutside);
  }, [editModal]);
```